# Using apache httpcomponent 4.0.x, how to send a http request without the header "Connection: Keep-Alive" from a client prgram?

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, keep-alive

I'm using apache httpcomponent 4.0.x.

How to send a http request without the header "Connection: Keep-Alive" from a client prgram?

For some reason, the Connection header is always set to keep-alive no matter what the http version is set to.  Version http 1.0. or 1.1 doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the version to 1.0 and it still adds "Connection: Keep-Alive" you should report it as bug at the project's [bug tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT). HTTP 1.0 does not support persistent connections so the header should not be added.